# Type checking issues with using pnpm and typescript together

Tags: typescript, types, symlink, typechecking, pnpm

As I understand from [tutorial](https://pnpm.js.org/docs/en/how-peers-are-resolved.html) pnpm creates symlinked `.registry.npmjs.org` and other entries point under `node_modules`. My project is on `typescript` and I have `@types` for typings in `node_modules`. But this `@types` has also in `node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/@types`. So I'm getting an error like:

`/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/@types/jquery/3.3.5/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(32,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'jQuery'.`

...and

`/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(28,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'jQuery'.`

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "scripts",
    "src/contracts"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you already set `"exclude": ["node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org"]` in your `tsconfig.json` file?  That's the first thing I would try, but I'm not posting it as an answer because I'm not very confident it will work.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen yes, I've tried that, but it doesn't help... Also I've tried ```"typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types"]``` with it

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.  `tsc --traceResolution` might help.  If you can't spot the problem from the output, post it in the question and I will look.

Comment: @AlexFilatov what version of typescript you use? I know that v1 had issues with symlinks but v2/3 works fine. Actually pnpm is written in typescript and we don't have these issues with typescript 2

Comment: @ZoltanKochan `"typescript": "^2.8.3",`

Comment: @ZoltanKochan seems that you haven't this issue because your are using typings and manually set path to `include` option in tsconfig.json. In my case I'm using @types instead of it which install via npm and is placed in node_modules/@types

Comment: pnpm uses `@types` as well, see [package.json](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/master/packages/pnpm/package.json#L85-L96).

Comment: @AlexFilatov do you have a repository on GitHub that reproduces the issue?

Comment: seems that I've fixed this issue. It was because of my code. I have duplicated link in my contracts folder typings for kendo where explicitly to set import on `<reference path="./../../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />`. I've removed this row and the issue dissapears

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to my tsconfig.json file worked for me:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveSymlinks": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]` worked.

By default `tsc` will look for types in all `node_modules/@types` folders.

You can test which files are being include by calling `tsc --listFiles`.

I think because this file is included by `typescript` itself, then it will also include all files in the pnpm repo store `node_modules/.pnpm/@types`.

```
xxx/node_modules/.pnpm/typescript@3.9.7/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
```

In my case I had multiple versions of React sitting in there that were getting read.

Comment: After doing this, I still got an error because typescript resolved files in `.pnpm`: `Type 'import("c:/Users/rajas/Documents/GitHub/meal-planner/node_modules/rc-menu/lib/interface").MenuClickEventHandler' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/rajas/Documents/GitHub/meal-planner/node_modules/.pnpm/rc-menu@9.0.12_react-dom@17.0.2+react@17.0.2/node_modules/rc-menu/lib/interface").MenuClickEventHandler'.`